# Android icon mipmap value not working on button

Tags: android, android-mipmap

I am trying to get a button with an image working on Android. I tried the following:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

The button shows without the image.

Comment: where you want to put image?

Comment: I just want a button with an image instead of text. The image is in the res/mipmap folder, where android studio puts it after you import the image asset.

Comment: You should not use the `mipmap` folder other than for the app icon. For the graphical resources use `drawable`.

Answer (score 3):

**#. If you want a `Button` with only background `Image`, Try this:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

[image]

**OR,** you can use `ImageButton` as below:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

[image]

**#. If you want a `Button` with `Text` and background `Image`, Try this:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

[image]

**#. If you want a `Button` with `Text` and left drawable `Icon`, Try this:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />`
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Find the solution a bit hacky, but suffices. Thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer if it is useful.Cheers